# Javascript triple select option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I've almost tried everything with javascript and jquery to make a triple select option menu,
but I still haven't figure it out.

Maybe you can help me?, thats actually exactly this what im trying to do, try to click little bit around here:

`http://www2.dba.dk/asp/indrykning/annoncevalg.asp?rubrikId=47601`

This is how mine look like, but i don't know how to put the third menu in:
`http://jsfiddle.net/L2jMn/`

And im gonna get all values from a database, so i don't know if its the right way i've have done it now.

I hope somebody has a solution for this, thanks!

Comment: please show your codes, what you have tried.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you post some code? Are you trying to create one menu that allows you to select more than one option? Three seperate menus? Is the problem getting the results or are you trying to dynamically generate the markup?

Comment: It's little bit hard to explain, but I just want to have 1 select menu that opens another one, depends what you have chose. Just like on that link. I just can't figure it how to do it.

Comment: i have pasted a jdfiddle now, you can watch: http://jsfiddle.net/L2jMn/

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 3 lists and subscribe to the `onChange` event to update the other ones. Check http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/javascript/ken/tripleMenu.htm or http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/triplecombo.shtml